# Get data from other table column Laravel 8 Eloquent

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

so I want to retrieve data from other's table column, and here's the code:

```php
    $tokoId = Toko::select('id')->where('user_id', auth()->id())->get();
```

since later I'll use the result for my other code which only requires the number from the $tokoId to show the data, like this:

```php
    $orders = SubOrder::where('toko_id', $tokoId)->get();
```

at first, I just write it like that, until I load the script and shows nothing, after some digging later I found out that instead of only giving the number, it gives output like " 'id':1 ". 
so are there any possible ways just to take the number only? or maybe any other writing method?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to use [firstWhere](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_firstWhere) :

```
$tokoId = Toko::select('id')->firstWhere('user_id', auth()->id())->id;
```

then you could use it in your code:

```
$orders = SubOrder::where('toko_id', $tokoId)->get();
```